# Binary Fuse Filter adding and deleting keys

Tags: membership, approximate, probabilistic-programming

Reading the paper for [binary fuse filters](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.01174), I realized that there are no sections for adding or removing keys. I was looking at this as a potential upgrade for Cuckoo filters but adding and deleting keys are important for the business logic.

Looking at the algorithm for filter construction, it seems like all the data needs to be present up front. Does this mean that the filter will be **immutable** upon creation and require a complete re-construction if anything needs to be added or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper confirms that all data must be presented up front to create the filter. An optimized Cuckoo variant could be the Morton filter.